# How to append using PrintWriter in Java

Tags: java, file, append, fileoutputstream, printwriter

My `Board` class has a `write` method like this

```
public void write(FileOutputStream fo) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(fo,true);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            String formatted="%3d";
            for (int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                out.append(String.format(formatted,arr[i][j]));
            }
            out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
```

I used this board to solve Unblock Me game, in my `BFSSolution` class, after finishing solving, I want to write `start` and `goal` board to my `output1.txt` file

```
fo=new FileOutputStream("output\\output1.txt");
start.write(fo);
goal.write(fo);
```

`start` and `goal` is two instances of `Board` class. But it did not append at all, neither write anything

How can I append?

I want to use `FileOutputStream` as a parameter of `write` method, because I will have many other `input2.txt` `input3.txt` with corresponding `output2.txt` `output3.txt`, so I did not use the specified path in `write` method

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to close PrintWriter

```
 public void write(FileOutputStream fo) throws IOException{
    PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(fo,true);
    .....
    out.close();// To save need to close PrintWriter.
}
```

Comment: If I do this, after finishing `start.write(fo)`, the method `goal.write(fo)` does not append

Comment: Than you need to change the design of your code, so that you can reuse the write method. But to write into file, you must close the resource.